# Compiling only one column from fixed width txt file and including file name Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Full disclosure I'm a chemist and have limited experience with Excel VBA.  I have an instrument that only will export fixed width text files.  We generate thousands of these and it's tedious to pull the data out of it.  It's just two columns of data in each file.  I'd like to have a macro that will compile all of the data on one sheet to make it faster to work with.  I only want the column that has the numerical data in it which would be column B in the file and I would like to have the text file name above that data.  Is this possible?  I have a macro that will search whatever folder you specify and will compile the data but it pulls in both columns and does not include the file name.  Any suggestions on how to modify the code?  I have put this together from posts I have found googling and trial and error.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is an example of what the data looks like in the text file.
[image]
[Text01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3LH.png)

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
    Dim importrow As Long
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                 (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    With ActiveSheet'''

        For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen

            importrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
              Destination:=.Cells(importrow, 1))
                .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
                .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(32)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With


        Next txtfile

        For Each qt In .QueryTables
            qt.Delete
        Next qt

    End With

    MsgBox "Done !", vbInformation, "SUCCESS !"

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question with a small snippet of data.  We can then test a proposed answer before we post it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent there should be a photo of the text file here.  Let me know if that isn't what you're looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and included some file I/O to read each of the text files in turn, place the name of the file in the first blank cell in column B, and then list all of the numerical data below that, then repeat for the next file in the next column. In my sample code, I've set the data to be read from column 30 in the text file - you may need to change this.

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim txtfile As Variant
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                 (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
    With ActiveSheet '''
        lngCol = 2
        For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
            lngRow = 1
            .Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = Dir(txtfile)
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
            intFile = FreeFile
            Open txtfile For Input As intFile
            Do
                Line Input #intFile, strInput
                .Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = Mid(strInput, 30)
                lngRow = lngRow + 1
            Loop Until EOF(intFile)
            Close #intFile
            lngCol = lngCol + 1
        Next txtfile
    End With
    MsgBox "Done !", vbInformation, "SUCCESS !"
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is sort of what I'm looking for but I want each data set to be in their own column.  Not sure how to edit this code to do that.  Any tips?

Comment: Code modified to place each file's data in a separate column.

Comment: This is great!  Where in the code is it pulling the path from?  I want to try to modify it so that it shows just the file name and not the whole path.  I've been trying some things but keep breaking it.

Comment: And modified again to use `.Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = Dir(txtfile)` to show just the file name.